# How to Encrypt 100% of web server?

Tags: ssl

I have read "openssl cookbook" (https://doc.lagout.org/security/openssl-cookbook.pdf) which recommends to :

> Encrypt 100% of Your Web Site

**But does installing and deploying a "certificated secured web server with ssl" , means that the files are encytped ?**

I mean, if the server contain some files, for example www.example.com/myfile.xml , is this file must be encrypted for ssl to function properly ?

As far as I understand, it doesn't have to be encrypted, even in ssl web server.

I plan to use Nginx web server (though it is not important for this question).

Comment: The statement is ambiguous.  "Encrypt 100% of Your Web Site" can mean both transit and files at rest.  Transit is covered by others here.  At rest depends on the OS of the webserver and how you might wish to encrypt files or partitions.

Comment: I agree about the ambiguity. I could not understand if the book means that files should be encrypted in web filesystem (aside frin to the ssl for transfer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means serve all of your content over HTTPS which is SSL encrypted. So if someone comes to he plain http://example.com, you redirect them to https://example.com.

Comment: Hi, I mean if the server contain some files, for example www.example.com/myfile.xml , is this file encrypted ?

Comment: In transit vs locally. You should encrypt 100% of the data in transit. That's what the cookbook means. TLS/SSL will read the data, encrypt it and send it. (Kind of, but explains what @ransh is asking)

Comment: In;less you have taken measures, it will not be encrypted at rest. It will though be encrypted on the wire if you server it over HTTPS.